# Dependency diagram in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dependencies, circular-dependency

Is there a way to see how libraries in my Flutter package depend on each other?
Under libraries, I mean internal libraries,  dart files under 'lib'.
Also, it would be great to check for circular dependencies between the libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: dependency diagram example]

[LayerLens](https://pub.dev/packages/layerlens) can continuously auto-generate dependency diagrams for your package.

Answer (score 130):

You can use below command to see your flutter app's dependency graph.

```
flutter pub deps
```

The dependency information is printed as a tree, a list, or a compact list.

[image]

Comment: It is very interesting to know. However, I am interested to see internal dependencies in my application, not external. I updated my question to make it clear.

Comment: Pass the `--no-dev` option to hide `dev_dependencies`.

Comment: dude you rock

Answer (score 20):

I was also looking for a tool to show *internal* dependencies but couldn't find one. So I wrote a tool called Lakos to visualize Dart/Flutter library dependencies in Graphviz. Lakos will visualize dependencies inside your project, not external package dependencies. Lakos will also warn about dependency cycles with an exit code.

https://pub.dev/packages/lakos

Example usage:

```
lakos --metrics . | dot -Tpng -Gdpi=200 -o lakos_example.png
```

The output will look similar to this:

[image: Lakos dependency graph example]

Comment: Beautiful!  This worked great for me to understand the screens hierarchy of a new project.

Comment: This is really great @Oleg Alexander, exactly what I was looking for! 
However, the graphs tend to get very hairy for larger projects. Is there a way to produce a graph only at the coarser level of subdirectories (I believe you call them "subgraphs" in lakos)?

Comment: @user18184 Thanks for the kind words. Unfortunately, there's no way to treat the subdirectories as nodes themselves. But you could try rendering the nodes as points, like this: lakos . | dot -Tpng -Gdpi=200 -Nshape=point -o example.png

Comment: 1. Install the Graphviz Interactive Preview extension for the VS Code
2. $ dart pub global activate lakos
3. $ flutter pub add lakos
4. $ lakos -o dot_images/lakos.metrics_no_test.dot -m -i test/** .
5. open the generated lakos.metrics_no_test.dot
6. press the preview button

Comment: I'm in quite a big project, I'm creating .svg but it is cutoff from the bottom, can't see much, any ideas?